# Serial port and multithreading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am a beginner at C# and would like some advice on how to solve the following problem:

I would like to continuously read from the serial port and store that data in an SQL database and write it to a text file simultaneously.

Is there any way that you can continuously read from the serial port and use that data in two separate threads without them also being in the while loop?

My code for my SQL:

```
public static void SQL_Logger(string data)
{
    //Connect to database
    PHINS_Connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=PHINSDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
    PHINS_Connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, PHINS_Connection); //creates executing comman
                                                                      //Query for creating the table
    //Execute the query
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (data.Contains("Ambient"))
    {
        //Query for inserting a column into the table created above with the roll data
        sql = "insert into PHINS_Data (valueType, value) values ('Ambient Temp'," + 199 + ")";

        //Create and execute the insert query
        command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, PHINS_Connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

And the code for the textLogger:

```
public static void textLogger(string text, string path)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

And the main program:

```
class Program
{
    static SerialPort newPort = new SerialPort("COM9", 9600);

    static SQLiteConnection PHINS_Connection;

    static string sql = "create table PHINS_Data (valueType varchar(20), value decimal(10, 3 ))"; // Creates table

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("PHINSDatabase.sqlite");

        string path = "PHINS-R-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".txt";
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path)) { }

        newPort.Open();

        Thread myNewThread = new Thread(() => textLogger(data, path));
        Thread myNewThread2 = new Thread(() => SQL_Logger(data));

        while (true)
        {
            data = newPort.ReadLine();

            myNewThread.Start();
            myNewThread2.Start();
        }
```

Every time I do this it tries to restart the thread every time the loop executes. Is it possible to continuously read the data and pass it to the two threads?

Comment: you could write some DataAdapter, which is in the while loop and provides threadsafe methods for the other two or more applications

Comment: Yes. Use two thread-safe queues. The reader writes messages to the queues. The threads dequeue messages from the queue and write them to their respective locations. TPL Dataflow has many features that might be useful when implementing this.

Comment: ok thank you. Do you have any examples of how i can implement thread safe queues here? Apologies, i am a complete beginner with this.

Comment: Take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks very much.